# iOS4.3 UILocalNotification don't support [NSCalendar +autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] as repeatCalendar?

Tags: iphone, ios

When I set [NSCalendar +autoupdatingCurrentCalendar] as the repeat calendar of UILocalNotification, then call [UIApplication -scheduleLocalNotification:] with the UILocalNotification, the local notification don't get scheduled!

is this a bug of iOS 4.3?

this is the code:

```
UILocalNotification *l = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
l.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30];
l.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alert time :%@,time zone %@",l.fireDate,l.timeZone];
l.alertAction = @"OK";
l.hasAction = YES;
l.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
l.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
[application scheduleLocalNotification:l];

NSLog("all local notifs: %@", [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications])   //empty array
```

Comment: Why do you set a `repeatCalendar` if you don't set a `repeatInterval`?  Does is work on iOS 5/6?

Comment: Yes, it works on both iOS 5.1& 6.0, both device and simulator. But it doesn't work on neither iOS 4.3 device nor simulator.

Comment: But why do you set a `repeatCalendar` without setting a `repeatInterval`? Do you want the notification to repeat or not?

Comment: that's just a demo dude, you can treat the repeatInterval as 0.

Comment: @MartinR It doesn't change anything with a repeatInterval, I've updated the code though.